# R: ylim and xlab/ylab in plot() for grofit package not working

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a growth spline for the variable "ipen" against "year" in [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/grofit.csv) data. The code I am using is:

```
grofit <- read.csv('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/grofit.csv')
# install.packages(c("grofit"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(grofit)
growth = gcFitSpline(grofit$year, grofit$ipen)
plot(growth)
```

This works fine, and produces the plot below. But the problem is that (a) I can't change the default labels with `xlab` or `ylab` options, and (b) I can't change the scale of x-axis to be (0,100) with `ylim=c(0,100)` in the `plot()` statement. I could not find any pointers in the `grofit()`documentation.  [image: this].

Comment: I would take the  `plot.gcFitSpline()` function and customize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't directly use `plot` on the `gcFitSpline` result, but rather use `str(growth)` to explore the structure of the curve fit object and determine what you want to plot, or look at `plot.gcFitSpline` code (just type the name of the function without parentheses in the console and press Enter!)

For instance:

```
growth = gcFitSpline(grofit$year, grofit$ipen)

plot (grofit$year, grofit$ipen, pch=20, cex=0.8, col="gray", ylim=c(0, 100),
     ylab="Growth", xlab="Year", las=1)
points(growth$fit.time, growth$fit.data, t="l", lwd=2)
```

This gives:

[image: result grofit plot]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the `grofit` documentation does have a pointer about this:

> ...   Other graphical parameters may also passed as arguments [sic]. This has currently no effect and is only meant to fulfill the requirements of a generic function.

You may have to rewrite the `plot.gcFitSpline` function specific to the graphical parameters you want, but there might be a reason that the function is the way it is.

BTW, I'm not sure it's a great idea to give your data the same name as the package you're using.